# Can I stop Sublime Text from messing with my input?

Tags: sublime-text

When I type in sublime text, it adds/eats parenthesis, quotes, etc.  I spend as much time deleting the extra characters the editor adds in as it saves by adding them.  In fact, I think it's a net negative.  Can I just disable all of the default screwing around it does with my text?

The only time I want sublime text to insert extra text is HTML close tags.  Are there any extensions that do this?  I'd like to disable all other text insertion from all plugins I'm using.  For example, when using elixir, when I type `do` it turns into `@doc """ """`.  This is never what I want.

I've seen other answers where people have to remap input just to avoid sublime text screwing things up.  Is there really not some way to just make it not screw around with my text in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your user settings Preferences -> Settings - User:

```
"auto_match_enabled" : false
```

This will stop the brackets being added automatically.